# How to directly print a Report without going through Crystal Reports Viewer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I wrote this code to print a Crystal report.. but I got error

> 'missing parameters'...

```
ReportDocument rdoc = new ReportDocument();
rdoc .Load (Application.StartupPath +"\\"+@"REPORTS\SalaryReport.rpt");

rdoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

ParameterFields pfs = new ParameterFields();

ParameterField pfv = new ParameterField();
ParameterDiscreteValue pdv1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
pfv.Name = "fd";
pdv1.Value = fd;
pfv.CurrentValues.Add(pdv1);
pfs.Add(pfv);

ParameterField pfv1 = new ParameterField();
ParameterDiscreteValue pdv11 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
pfv1.Name = "td";
pdv11.Value = td;
pfv1.CurrentValues.Add(pdv11);
pfs.Add(pfv1);

ParameterField pfv2 = new ParameterField();
ParameterDiscreteValue pdv12 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
pfv2.Name = "department";
pdv12.Value = Dept;
pfv2.CurrentValues.Add(pdv12);
pfs.Add(pfv2);
crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = pfs;
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rdoc;

PrinterSettings getprinterName = new PrinterSettings();
rdoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = getprinterName.PrinterName;
rdoc.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 1, 1);
```

So help to solve this issue....how to print directly without going through Crystal Reports Viewer?

Answer (score 2):

So Simple

1. Remove thes lines:

   ```
   crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
   crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
   ```
2. Add this line:

   ```
   objRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Please use **PrintToPrinter** method to directly print crystal report.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691452%28VS.71%29.aspx

http://www.nullskull.com/q/10110521/print-crystal-report-without-viewing.aspx

Comment: Am use without ParameterFields in my report means i got output but i am use ParameterFields means i got error 'missing parameters',...

Answer (score 1):

Printing directly to the printer is not going to solve your problem. The Crystal Report requires parameters to be set correctly and they're not for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
reportname report1=new reportname(); 
report1.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Portrait;
report1.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperA4;
report1.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 15);
```

use these codes with function(Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<BusLib.Report.ReportParameter> ParaList = new List<BusLib.Report.ReportParameter>();
            ParaList.Add(new BusLib.Report.ReportParameter("Para1", Value1));
            ParaList.Add(new BusLib.Report.ReportParameter("Para2", Value2));
            ParaList.Add(new BusLib.Report.ReportParameter("Para3", Value3));
            ParaList.Add(new BusLib.Report.ReportParameter("Para4", Value4));
```

After That..

```
public void SetParameters(List<BusLib.Report.ReportParameter> pParams)
    {
        if (pParams == null) { return; }
        try
        {
            foreach (BusLib.Report.ReportParameter pPara in pParams)
            {
                CReport.SetParameterValue(pPara.ParameterName, pPara.ParameterValue);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Val.Message(Ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

you should try this ... you will get definetly success...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void PrintReport(string reportPath, string PrinterName)
{
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rptDoc =
                        new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
    rptDoc.Load(reportPath);

    CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins objPageMargins;
    objPageMargins = rptDoc.PrintOptions.PageMargins;
    objPageMargins.bottomMargin = 100;
    objPageMargins.leftMargin = 100;
    objPageMargins.rightMargin = 100;
    objPageMargins.topMargin = 100;
    rptDoc.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(objPageMargins);
    //rptDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName;
    rptDoc.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
}

private void PrintToPrinter()
{
    PrintReport(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath +"\\VCrpfrmprint.rpt","Send To OneNote 2010");
}
```

`rptDoc.PrintToPrinter` method prints the specified pages of the report to the printer selected with the help of the `PrintOptions.PrinterName` property.
If no printer is selected, the default printer specified in the report will be used.

We are using `PrintToPrinter` method as :

```
public void PrintToPrinter (int nCopies , boolean collated , int startPage , int endPage );
```

where:

- `nCopies` indicates the number of copies to print.
- `collated` indicates whether to collate the pages.
- `startPage` indicates the first page to print.
- `endPage` indicates the last page to print.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Print/View P.O? Please be patient as P.O may take few seconds to load.", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                pl.POId = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = bl.PurchaseOrderPrint(pl);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Reports.PuchaseOrder rpt = new Reports.PuchaseOrder();
                    Print f = new Print();
                    rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
                    f.CRV.ReportSource = rpt;
                    f.Show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```